# changing the color of anchor element while clicking on enclosing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the color of my anchor element from black to white while the enclosing div is clicked.
code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".settings-list-container").click(function() {
    $(".functionHyperlink").css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="settings-container" ng-controller="settingController">
  <div id="settings-list">
    <div class="settings-list-container" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-click="openTab(element,$event);" target="_self">
      <a href="" class="functionHyperlink" target="_self">{{element.caption}}&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="settings-list-content" ng-include="tabV.view">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: I think the code there is what he has tried, pretty much, huh?

Comment: I tried this jquery code but it doesn't work:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".settings-list-container").click(function(){
        $(".functionHyperlink").css("background-color", "red");
    });
});

Comment: you might click somewhere else while testing this. It should work https://jsfiddle.net/rxtr2pnw/ The green background there is of the container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use angular.element() and css selector

```
angular.element('.functionHyperlink').css('color', '#fff');
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `toggleClass()` to add/remove a pre-defined CSS rule you apply to the `.settings-list-container` element. This class can then be set to affect the child `.functionHyperlink` element, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".settings-list-container").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.functionHyperlink { 
  color: #000;
}

.settings-list-container.active .functionHyperlink {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="settings-container" ng-controller="settingController">
  <div id="settings-list">
    <div class="settings-list-container" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-click="openTab(element,$event);" target="_self">
      <a href="" class="functionHyperlink" target="_self">{{element.caption}}&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="settings-list-content" ng-include="tabV.view"></div>
</div>
```

If you only want the colour to be added once, change `toggleClass()` to `addClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to achieve the color change **while** clicking. You could try so with pure CSS like this.

```css
.settings-list-container:active .functionHyperlink {
    color: white;
}
```

Or you could go by jQuery and add a class while clicking the div:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    $('.settings-list-container').each(function() {
        $(this).bind('mousedown', function() {
            $(this).find('.functionHyperlink').addClass('inverted');
        }).bind('mouseup', function() {
            $(this).find('.functionHyperlink').removeClass('inverted');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.functionHyperlink.inverted {
    color: white;
}
```

If you want the element to **stay** inverted, use the following jQuery instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    $('.settings-list-container').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find('.functionHyperlink').toggleClass('inverted');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No just clicking....i want the color of the anchor element to stay white when the enclosing div is clicked.

Comment: Please check the Developer Tools to see, if the class "inverted" applies to the element’s HTML output, when you click on it. If that’s the case, it is a CSS problem and not a JavaScript problem.